# how can I directly call a number in react native without opening dialer for android

Tags: javascript, react-native, listener, phone-call

I am working with dialing application where application can simply automatically call numbers one by one from the list . The main issue here is ,I don't want the dialer shown every time when call is triggered. In Short how can I directly call a number in app without opening  dialer in react native for android platform.

Answer (score 1):

Try using [react-native-immediate-phone-call](https://github.com/wumke/react-native-immediate-phone-call)

```
import RNImmediatePhoneCall from 'react-native-immediate-phone-call';
...
RNImmediatePhoneCall.immediatePhoneCall('0123456789');
...
```

Comment: I have tried this I am getting an error "null is not an object ...evaluating '_reactNative.NativeModules.RNImmediatePhoneCall.immediatePhoneCall')"

Comment: Can we also do a video call with this? I want to directly call a person in video mode.

Answer (score 0):

I have seen to much stuff about that so I finally get the solution .So  the solution is to make a bridge b/w react native and java ,so that u can call java  functionality to make a direct call using this code.
`String dial = "tel:" + phn_number;   reactcontext.startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL, Uri.parse(dial)));`

first check permission. If it is not granted then first ask for the permission and then dial number.

```
if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(reactcontext,
        Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(reactcontext.getCurrentActivity(),
            new String[]{Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE}, REQUEST_CALL);
} else {
    String dial = "tel:" + phn_number;
    reactcontext.startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL, Uri.parse(dial)));

}
```

Make sure u add permission in manifest like.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use [react-native-send-intent](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-send-intent) library

It's very important to ask for permission in your AndroidManifest.xml file if you need to use Phone Calls directly. You can add an optional second parameter, to fix the default phone app.

`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />`

How to Use

```
    var SendIntentAndroid = require("react-native-send-intent");

    SendIntentAndroid.sendPhoneCall("+1 234567 8900", true);
```

Sample Code

```
    var SendIntentAndroid = require("react-native-send-intent");

    const InitiateCall = async () => {

        const granted = await PermissionsAndroid.request(
            PermissionsAndroid.PERMISSIONS.CALL_PHONE,
            {
                title: "App Needs Permission",
                message:
                    `Myapp needs phone call permission to dial direclty `,

                buttonNegative: "Disagree",
                buttonPositive: "Agree"
            }
        );

        if (granted === PermissionsAndroid.RESULTS.GRANTED) {
            SendIntentAndroid.sendPhoneCall("+1 234567 8900", true);
            console.log("You dialed directly");
        } else {
            console.log("No permission");
        }

    }

 

    return (
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => InitiateCall ()}>
                   <YourComponent/>
        </TouchableOpacity>
    )
```

You can use the above function in  onPress event